# Begin Thread execution as soon as it is created(Multithreading)

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

```
    class Mythread implements Runnable {
        Thread thrd;

        Mythread(String name){
         thrd = new Thread(this, name) ;
        }

        public static Mythread createAndStart(String name) {
            Mythread mythrd = new Mythread(name) ;
            mythrd.thrd.start() ;
            return mythrd ;
        }

         public void run() {
             System.out.println(thrd.getName()+ " Starting.") ;
         try {
             for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                 Thread.sleep(400);
                 System.out.println("In "+ thrd.getName() +", count is "+i) ; 
             }
         }
         catch(Exception E) {
         }
         System.out.print(thrd.getName()+" terminating.") ;
     }
 }


 public class demo{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main thread Starting") ;
        Mythread mt = Mythread.createAndStart("child #1") ;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++) {
            System.out.print(".") ;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread Ending") ;
    }
}
```

In the above code, why can't we write **thrd.start() ;** instead of **mythrd.thrd.start() ;** in CreateAndStart method. What does that mean? Also, Why do we return mythrd object in the same method?
Since the CreateAndStart method is returning a mythrd reference to **mt** in **main** method, what would be the use of **mt**?

Comment: In a static context, you need to instatiate the object and enter the method through it despite variable being declared in the same class. https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/why-non-static-variable-cannot-be.html

Comment: why do we return **mythrd** reference in CreateAndStatic method.

Comment: Since the method is static, the method can be called without `Mythread` being insntatiated. The method creates and returns an instance of `Mythread` without doing `new Mythread(name)` first by only having reference to the class itself. I suspect it was done like that due to simplicity, and you can also move all the code from `createAndStart()` to the `main` method inside `demo` class and the result will be the same.

Comment: it's from a book that claims that this way of implementing multithreading is much improved than implementing it in the main method but its a bit confusing.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do to get the same result as the book. I suggest you start with what seems easiest and work from there so the consepts doesn't get too confusing.

Comment: Is there any update? Is the problem solved for you? Or is there anything still unclear?